# How should I make this css transition like in discord app?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a css transition which I saw in the discord app, there are two squares which *scales, rotates, and translates* in **clockwise** direction.

Initially, they are on the diagonal positions.

Below is my attempt to that, but I am not getting it quite right.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10%;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move 4s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: move 4s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes move {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(100px) rotate(90deg) scale(0.5)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px) translateY(100px) rotate(180deg) scale(1)
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(100px) rotate(270deg) scale(0.5)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieved it, fortunately got a working version [here](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/)

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10%;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes move {
  25% {transform: translateX(42px) rotate(-90deg) scale(0.5) }
  50% {transform: translateX(42px) translateY(42px) rotate(-180deg) }
  75% {transform: translateX(0px) translateY(42px) rotate(-270deg) scale(0.5) }
  100% {transform: rotate(-360deg) }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because both squares should follow the same path, what we can do is use the same keyframes but force square two to start half way through the animation this can be done by giving `animation-delay:` a *negative* value of half of the total animation time, in this case -2.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10%;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: move 4s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: move 4s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

@keyframes move {
  25% {
    transform: translateX(100px) rotate(90deg) scale(0.5)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px) translateY(100px) rotate(90deg) scale(1)
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(0px) translateY(100px) rotate(90deg) scale(0.5)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added a animation delay coz both have same direction which is clockwise. That's how I am using the same animation for both.

Comment: @bhansa I've edited my answer so both animations can use the same keyframes.